# Number of ways to partition n fixed points using cubic grids

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of different ways to partition $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ using cubic grid partitions of given cube size h?

Notation: $n$ is a positive integer. The class of cubic grid partitions of $\mathbb{R}^d$ consists of elements $P = \{\Pi_{i=1}^{d}[k_ih,(k_i+1)h]: k_i \in \mathbb{Z}, i=1,...,d\}$

Comment: shouldn't it be $k_i+h$ instead of $(k_i+1)h$?

Comment: You are almost right. Cells of the form $\Pi_{i=1}^{d}[k_i,k_i+h]$ don't lead to a cubic partition. I was missing a factor $h$ which I added. Hope it resolves the error.